# Filter an existing itemgroup so it only includes files that match some condition

Tags: msbuild, filtering

How do you filter an existing ItemGroup based on a specific condition, such as file extension or the item's metadata?

For this example, I'll use the file extension. I'm trying to filter the 'None' ItemGroup defined by VS so that my target can operate on all files of a given extension.

For example, the following may be defined:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\file1.ext" />
    <None Include="..\file2.ext" />
    <None Include="..\file.ext2" />
    <None Include="..\file.ext3" />
    <None Include="..\file.ext4" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I want to filter the 'None' ItemGroup above so it only includes the `ext` extension. Note that I do **not** want to specify all the extensions to exclude, as they'll vary per project and I'm trying to make my target reusable without modification.

I've tried adding a `Condition` within a target:

```
<Target Name="Test">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Filtered
            Include="@(None)"
            Condition="'%(Extension)' == 'ext'"
            />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="None: '%(None.Identity)'"/>
    <Message Text="Filtered: '%(Filtered.Identity)'"/>
</Target>
```

But sadly, it doesn't work. I get the following for output:

```
Test:
  None: '..\file1.ext'
  None: '..\file2.ext'
  None: '..\file.ext2'
  None: '..\file.ext3'
  None: '..\file.ext4'
  Filtered: ''
```

Comment: I believe %(Extension) needs to be '.ext'

Comment: `%(Extension)` should be expanded to the extension of the item in `@(None)` being examined which is what I want compared to 'ext', the target extension.

Comment: I mean it literally needs to be '.ext', as in with a dot as first char, works just fine then.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Filtered Include="@(None)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.ext'" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.
`error MSB4190: The reference to the built-in metadata "Extension" at posi
tion 1 is not allowed in this condition "'%(Extension)' == '.ext'".`

Comment: I second the `<Target>` comment, with one addition: In a normal programming language, you would expect the `<Filtered>` ItemGroup to be scoped to the `<Target>` it is contained in. Not so in MSBuild: If you define your `<Filtered>` inside a target, it will be available to other targets, so if you need the ItemGroup in another target, just set your `BeforeTargets` attribute for the new `<Target>` to be the target where you need the ItemGroup.

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki make sure you put the ItemGroup into a target when you want to access well-known item metadata. Otherwise you get that error.

Answer (score 2):

For advanced filtering I suggest using the `RegexMatch` from [MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks).

In this Example we will Filter for Versionnumbers

```
    <RegexMatch Input="@(Items)" Expression="\d+\.\d+\.\d+.\d+">
        <Output ItemName ="ItemsContainingVersion" TaskParameter="Output" />
    </RegexMatch>
```

> Install MSBuild Community Tasks via Nuget: PM> Install-Package MSBuildTasks or download it [here](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks)

Then Import it in your MSBuild Script:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>..\.build\</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)MsBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
```